# Revoke - (Use same selection for future launches)

Tags: android

In Android Studio when we check `Use same selection for future launches` while running app in device, then it will run app in same device in future.

I want revoke that setting so that I can choose again.

It is not measure problem, but I have to disconnect device physically to revoke it. Is there any IDE shortcut/ setting to revoke this setting preference?

Comment: You can go to **Run/Debug configurations** from where you deploy your app & in that config screen you can find checkbox to disable *Use same selection for future launches* feature.

Comment: @JeelVankhede that is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Should i add answer?

Comment: Yes you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to **Run/Debug configurations** from where you deploy your app & in that config screen you can find checkbox to disable *Use same selection for future launches* feature.

**Follow these steps :**

Step 1

[image: Img 1]

Step 2

Open ***Edit Configurations...***

Step 3

[image: Img 2]

*Uncheck the option.*

Answer (score 1):

Click on the app button -> Edit Configurations

[image: ScreenShot]

In general tab you can find the option for deployment target.